# In Ethereum what is read tx per second ( not write tx per second )

Tags: transactions, ethereum-classic

It is every where documented that how much tx per second ethereum can do (which is for writing) , but I want to know what is possible read tx per second ? and if difference then why

Comment: reading data from the blockchain does not involve mining, so you can theoretically do it "as fast as you want" (under the limitation of your connection with the node, the limitation of the node's connection with the network, and the limitation of the node's computation power)

Comment: Thanks got it, means it is limited to the system resource availability including hardware